# Compile and inject a page to ionic app on runtime

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a project that I need to add an Ionic Page Component from remote server on runtime. Firstly, I need to transpile the component from typescript before and deploy to a server. After that, on a button click event, I need to download the component and register that as ionic page. It would be very helpful if I can get help in generation of js from typescript file. The main problem on js generation is, I'm using webpack and webpack is changing all the imports into its own function calls and it contains random(?) numbers in it.
Second problem is that I can't get and register a page in runtime. I'm using lazy loading but couldn't find a way to register that page. I tried the following code but didn't work:

```
let injector = ReflectiveInjector
    .fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);
    // 1. Create module loader
    let loader = new SystemJsNgModuleLoader(this.compiler);
    loader.load("http://example-website.com/test-module")
    .then((nmf:NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
        // 2. create NgModuleRef
        let ngmRef = nmf.create(injector);
        let page = ngmRef.instance.page;
        // 3. Create component factory
        let cmpFactory = ngmRef
            .componentFactoryResolver
            .resolveComponentFactory(page);
        // 4. Create the component
        let componentRef = this.span.createComponent(cmpFactory, 0, injector,[]);
        // 5. Init the component name field.
        componentRef.instance.name = "TestPage";
        // 6. Refresh the component area.
        componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        componentRef.onDestroy(()=> {
            componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detach();
        });
    });
```

I'm using ionic 3, angular 5 with typescript 2.4.2.

Comment: I have never seen a module lazy loaded remotely, only from within the package created by the ionic CLI.

Comment: @PhilipBrack Oh, if I can inject a page without lazy loading, I'm ok with non-lazy loaded pages too.

Comment: Could you use [InAppBrowser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) for your purposes?  I do not believe you can inject a page from http, and I am not sure how easy it would be to lazy load from external site a module.

Comment: Hm, I can look InAppBrowser solution if I can't find any way to solve that problem with injecting to app module somehow. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. I didn't have time to look at it again actually.